# How to use the "cylinder function" of Matlab to create a surface of revolution?

Tags: matlab, 3d, geometry

I have been trying to develop a GUIDE program with MatLab that plots a surface of revolution but I just got wrong answers.

Here's what I tried:

```
b = str2double(get(handles.editB, 'string'));
Incremento = str2double(get(handles.editIncrement, 'string'));
x = a:Incremento:b;
y = a:Incremento:b;

helperFunction = get(handles.editFunction, 'string' );
myFunction = eval(helperFunction);
[X,Y,Z] = cylinder(myFunction);
surf(Y,X,Z);
title('Surface of Revolution');
```

In addition I have to mention that the previous code plots surfaces of revolution of a function as if the function were the inverse function. For example: I wanna try to plot the surface of revolution of x^2 then the program would output the surface of revolution of sqrt(x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answers you get are correct, but your expectations of this function are wrong. According to MATLAB documents:

> `[X,Y,Z] = cylinder(r)` returns the x-, y-, and z-coordinates of a cylinder using `r` to define a profile curve. **`cylinder` treats each element in `r` as a radius at equally spaced heights along the unit height of the cylinder.** The cylinder has 20 equally spaced points around its circumference.

In other words, this function considers the first and last elements of the vector `r` as cylinder radii at heights 0 and 1, respectively, and the other elements as cylinder radii at equally spaced heights in this interval. The following figure may explain this better:

[image]